# Can i make window unresizable in sokol using sokol-app.h?

Tags: c, c99, game-development

Is it possible to make window unresizable without pain of scaling graphics?

```c
#define SOKOL_IMPL
#include "sokol/sokol_app.h"

sapp_desc sokol_main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return (sapp_desc)
    {
        .window_title = "sokol-game",
        .width        = 800,
        .height       = 450,
        .init_cb      = sokol_on_init,
        .frame_cb     = sokol_on_frame,
        .event_cb     = sokol_on_event,
        // TODO: Is there way to let window unresizable?
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not directly supported now.

There is a discussion on Github, where the Sokol author suggests:

> I think the best way to implement this is via a config flag in sapp_desc, and then when creating the window omit the platform-specific "resizable flag" (in case you want to hack this yourself for now).

see https://github.com/floooh/sokol/issues/380

For example, you could remove the NSWindowStyleMaskResizable flag on MacOS, so that instead of

```
const NSUInteger style =
    NSWindowStyleMaskTitled |
    NSWindowStyleMaskClosable |
    NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable |
    NSWindowStyleMaskResizable;
```

it would look like this:

```
const NSUInteger style =
    NSWindowStyleMaskTitled |
    NSWindowStyleMaskClosable |
    NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable;
```

You would have to do this for all platforms you want to support.